# How to determine whether specified file is placed inside of the specified folder?

Tags: python

Let's say I have two paths: the first one (may be file or folder path): `file_path`, and the second one (may only be a folder path): `folder_path`. And I want to determine whether an object collocated with `file_path` is inside of the object collocated with `folder_path`.

I have an idea of doing this:

```
import os
...
def is_inside(file_path, folder_path):
  full_file_path   = os.path.realpath(file_path)
  full_folder_path = os.path.realpath(folder_path)
  return full_folder_path.startswith(full_file_path)
```

but I'm afraid there are some pitfalls in this approach. Also I think there must be a prettier way to do this.

The solution must work on Linux but it would be great if you propose me some cross-platform trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.commonprefix`. Here's an example based on your idea.

```
import os.path as _osp

def is_inside(file_path, folder_path):
    full_file_path = _osp.realpath(file_path)
    full_folder_path = _osp.realpath(folder_path)
    return _osp.commonprefix([full_file_path, full_folder_path]) == \
           full_folder_path
```

Comment: Well, isn't it pretty the same thing as I proposed in my question?

Comment: @ikostia - Yes and no. Under Linux (and probably under Windows) `commonprefix` can be implemented by matching the longest beginning substring. But if there's a platform Python is implemented on where that doesn't work for whatever reason, `commonprefix` will still work. You were pretty unspecific about the kinds of pitfalls you were worried about. If you were more specific I could give you a better answer.

Comment: Well I meant various pitfalls, ones I can miss at development time. I just thought maybe someone else solved this problem in a far different way and could explain me his choice. But now I see that probably thats the best way to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the file name from the file path and do

```
os.path.exists(full_folder_path + '/' + file_name)
```

Comment: That doesn't work if I want to check if '/home/ikostia/1.txt' is inside of '/home'. Your algorithm gives false while the right answer is true.